# Private Class within Namespace

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, typedef, private

I have a class within a namespace in a header file. The class requires a template type, and I only want certain types to be used. Below shows an example.

File a.hpp

```
// a.hpp
namespace a_ns {
template<class T>    
class a {
    // stuff
};
typedef a<double> a_double;
} // end of namespace
// stuff
```

File b.hpp

```
// b.hpp
#include <a.hpp>
namespace b_ns {
    typedef a_ns::a_double b;
}
```

File main.cpp

```
// main.cpp
#include "b.hpp"
int main() {
    b_ns::b my_b; // <<<--- I LIKE this!
    a_ns::a<float> my_a_which_is_not_allowed; // <<<--- I DO NOT LIKE THIS THOUGH! D:
}
```

So as you can see from the rather longed out example, the end objective is to NOT ALLOW the end user to declare a `class a` with `float` as the typename, and to only be able to use the pre-defined classes with specific types, as declared by `typedef a<double> a_double;`.

I thought this example above would allow this, however I was wrong, as I can create an `a<float>` as above, because I include `b.hpp`, which in turn includes `a.hpp`! So you see the problem! (hopefully?)

There is probably a simple solution, if this is at all possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to be able to use the type aliases and not use `a` directly, you can put it into an implementation namespace that users should know not to use:

```
namespace a_ns {

namespace detail {
    template<class T>        
    class a {
        // stuff
    };
}

typedef detail::a<double> a_double;
} // end of namespace
```

Now anything can use `a_double`, but to use `a` directly, your `detail` namespace would have to be dug into, and that's generally accepted as a bad thing to do. If a user decides they want to do that, they've already given up on staying out of trouble and you shouldn't take extra measures to stop them from hurting themself.

Comment: Actually I like this - I fear there is no way to defeat trouble making programmers.

Comment: @DieterLücking, Once you get over the fact that they have to deliberately dig themselves into the hole, you start worrying a lot less about preventing it. If they want to screw themselves over, let them. If there's something in there that can really help them, at least now they don't need a hack to get to it.

Comment: or as Herb Sutter puts it: defend against Murphy, not Machiavelli

Comment: Hmm yes, I quite like this. It's not exactly watertight, but as you say "If they deliberately screw themselves..." Guess it's an alright solution (+1)

Comment: @EdwardBird it's used all over the Boost libraries. Once you move to template libraries, there is really no stopping users from taking the source and defining whatever they want.

Comment: @TemplateRex I've just stumbled upon the various uses of the `static` keyword. Could I put `static` in front of my `class a { ...` to limit the scope of `class a` or does static only limit the scope of instances of a class, for example `static a my_a_which_is_static;`?

Comment: @EdwardBird You should ask a regular question, the comments are not the place to discuss this.

Comment: @EdwardBird, `static class {...} ...;` means the objects declared in that statement are static. It's been asked somewhere on here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can use a static_assert

```
#include <type_traits>
template <typename T>
class X
{
  T i;
  static_assert(!std::is_same<float,T>::value,"Don't use floating point");
};



int main()
{
    X<int> a;
    //X<float> b; fails at compile time
    return 0;
}
```

This will work as long as the variable is not const or volatile